# Convert a string to std filesystem path

Tags: c++, c++17

A file path is passed as a string. How do I convert this string to a [std::filesystem::path](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path)? Example:

```
#include <filesystem>

std::string inputPath = "a/custom/path.ext";
const std::filesystem::path path = inputPath; // Is this assignment safe?
```

Comment: I think it is ok  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/operator%3D

Comment: `path` [constructor 4](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/path) is called. _Constructs the path from a character sequence provided by source (4), which is a pointer or an input iterator to a null-terminated character/wide character sequence, an *std::basic_string* [...]_

Comment: @AnkurJyotiPhukan No, this isn't assignment.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, this *construction* is safe:

```
const std::filesystem::path path = inputPath; // Is this assignment safe?
```

That is not assignment, that is copy initialization. You are invoking this [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/path):

```
template< class Source >
path( const Source& source );
```

which takes:

> Constructs the path from a character sequence provided by source (4), which is a pointer or an input iterator to a null-terminated character/wide character sequence, **an `std::basic_string`** or an `std::basic_string_view`,

So you're fine. Plus, it would be *really* weird if you couldn't construct a `filesystem::path` from a `std::string`.

Answer (score 10):

I'm aware that this is a 5 year old question, but since it is still the top result for the search "string to filesystem::path" IMHO it requires some additional comment on usages on Windows (although the original question probably was implicitly focused on Linux, judging from the chosen path separator).

**For Windows systems**, the implicit construction of a filesystem::path from string **is not safe** with respect to encoding (despite the fact that it is legal according to the standard). If you have a path as a std::string that contains non-ASCII characters, you have to be absolutely clear about whether it is encoded in the local code-page or UTF-8 (there is no such distinction under Linux). The implicit construction shown in the question will assume encoding in the local code-page, while many 3rd party libraries will assume UTF-8 as the standard (e.g. QT in QString::toStdString() return UTF-8; strings in gRPC/protobuf should be expected being UTF-8 etc.). Therefore, you have to be very careful not to mix these:

```
const std::string path_as_string = "\xe4\xb8\xad"; //chinese character Zhong in UTF-8
const std::filesystem::path wrong_path = path_as_string; //looks innocent, but incorrect encoding is used!

std::ofstream stream;
stream.open(std::filesystem::current_path() / wrong_path); //create a file with the broken name
stream.close();
```

The correct way to construct the path in this case would be

```
const std::filesystem::path correct_path = std::filesystem::u8path(path_as_string);
```

Please also note, that this is a perfectly valid path, and you can easily create a file containing such characters using regular applications or the Windows Explorer. Due to the high potential to get the conversion wrong, IMHO it would have been preferable for Windows development, to not have any implicit constructor in the current situation, but [requests to have an option to disable that behavior in the STL implementations](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/909) have been rejected with reference to the standard. On the other hand, it seems that Windows will slowly move to UTF-8 as default code-page in the future (see e.g. [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/909#issuecomment-1015794617)). Until then, the above mentioned caveats should to be taken into account.

Comment: Yes. A point very well made. Thank you.