# Unable to pass non-ASCII filenames from NodeJS to C++ module

Tags: c++, node.js, path, node-modules

I want to send file path information from NodeJS to my own module (C++ using node-addon-api). Each side works independently (i.e. I can check/open files in NodeJS and C++). However, it fails if want to send path variables that include characters like ä, ö, ü, etc. from NodeJS to C++.

This is the code checking if a path exists, writing the path and result to a file and also returning that result:

```cpp
// PathJSON.h
#pragma once
#include <filesystem>
#include <format>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

namespace test_json {
  std::string checkPathInJSON(const char* json) {
    std::string pathString = json;
    std::filesystem::path p(pathString);
    std::string outString = "";
    if (std::filesystem::exists(p)) {
      outString = std::format("{};exists", pathString);
    }
    else {
      outString = std::format("{};MISSING", pathString);
    }
    std::filesystem::path logPath("d:/filelog.csv");
    std::ofstream ofs(logPath, std::ios::app);
    if (ofs.is_open()) {
      ofs << outString << std::endl;
      ofs.close();
    }
    return outString;
  }
}
```

```cpp
// Central.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "PathJSON.h"

int main() {
  std::string str = test_json::checkPathInJSON("D:/foo.txt");
  std::cout << str << std::endl;  // D:/foo.txt;exists
  str = test_json::checkPathInJSON("D:/föö.txt");
  std::cout << str << std::endl;  // D:/föö.txt;exists
}
```

Testing this code in a C++ project gives the expected results, both to the console as well to the file:

```
// filelog.csv
D:/foo.txt;exists  // correct
D:/föö.txt;exists  // correct
```

Here is the corresponding `NodeJS` module (adapted from the official ["hello world" example](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-examples/tree/main/src/1-getting-started/1_hello_world/node-addon-api)):

```cpp
// hello.cc
#include <iostream>
#include <napi.h>
#include "PathJSON.h"

Napi::String Method(const Napi::CallbackInfo& info) {
  Napi::Env env = info.Env();
  std::string str = "";
  if(info.Length() == 1 && info[0].IsString()) {
    std::string par = info[0].As<Napi::String>();
    std::cout << par << std::endl;
    str = test_json::checkPathInJSON(par.c_str());
  }
  return Napi::String::New(env, str);
}

Napi::Object Init(Napi::Env env, Napi::Object exports) {
  exports.Set(Napi::String::New(env, "hello"), Napi::Function::New(env, Method));
  return exports;
}

NODE_API_MODULE(node_api_1, Init);
```

Calling the module:

```js
// hello.js
console.log(addon.hello("D:/foo.txt"));
console.log(addon.hello("D:/föö.txt"));
```

which results in the following output:

```
// filelog.csv
D:/foo.txt;exists   // correct
D:/föö.txt;MISSING  // ERROR
```

As you can see, the module reports that the file containing special characters ("Umlaute") does not exist - yet, it is writing the correct filename to the log file and I have no idea where the issue is!

So, how I can fix this so that I can open files that contain non-ASCII characters?

Thank you in advance for your help!

P.S.: I have also tried to use `rapidjson` to pass the data (actually, this is what I usually use to pass all information). Also, I have tried different variations of the path, e.g. `D:\\föö.txt`, `D:\\\\föö.txt`, etc..

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43114174/convert-a-string-to-std-filesystem-path/73686919#73686919

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting `Napi::String` to a `std::string` gives you a [UTF-8](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api/blob/main/doc/string.md#operators) encoded string, the windows file APIs don't support UTF-8.

If instead you convert to `std::u16string` then `std::filesystem` should work as expected:

```
std::u16string par = info[0].As<Napi::String>();
std::filesystem::path p(par)
```

Comment: This is working, so thank you very much! However, I still don't understand how it can be that on the one hand, a UTF-8 encoded string is not fully supported, but on the other hand I get the correct path when using `p.c_str()`. Why don't I get a wrong strong here?

Comment: depends what `p` is and what you pass that to. That's why `std::u8string` has been introduced to resolve the ambiguity of multiple different 8-bit encodings being used with `char` and `std::string`