# Converting between string, wstring and u16string

Tags: c++, string, casting, c++20

My `C++` module receives a JSON string from NodeJS (node-addon-api) and then I'm using `rapidjson` to process the data, which requires `const char*`.

However, for certain functions (see my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77781276/unable-to-pass-non-ascii-filenames-from-nodejs-to-c-module)) I need the data as either `wstring` or `u16string`.

Either way, I need a way to convert between `std::string` / `const char*` and `std::u16string` / `const char16_t*`. I have searched the net and asked AI. Mostly, something like this is suggested:

```
std::wstring convert_to_wstring(const std::string& str) {
  std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>, wchar_t> conv;
  return conv.from_bytes(str);
}

std::string convert_from_wstring(const std::wstring& wstr) {
  std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>, wchar_t> conv;
  return conv.to_bytes(wstr);
}
```

However, Visual Studio 2022 complains that this is deprecated:

> **warning STL4017:** std::wbuffer_convert, std::wstring_convert, and the  header (containing std::codecvt_mode, std::codecvt_utf8, std::codecvt_utf16, and std::codecvt_utf8_utf16) are deprecated in C++17. (The std::codecvt class template is NOT deprecated.) The C++ Standard doesn't provide equivalent non-deprecated functionality; consider using MultiByteToWideChar() and WideCharToMultiByte() from <Windows.h> instead.

I tried that, (e.g. from [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693010/how-do-i-use-multibytetowidechar)), but also couldn't get it to work.

So, how do I convert between `string` and `u16string` **without** using `wstring_convert`?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do exactly what the warning message says:

> consider using MultiByteToWideChar() and WideCharToMultiByte() from <Windows.h> instead.

You can use `CP_UTF8` as the codepage for them, eg:

```
template<typename WideCharT>
std::basic_string<WideCharT> convert_UTF8_to_UTF16(const std::string& str) {
  const char *str_ptr = str.c_str();
  int str_len = static_cast<int>(str.size());
  int wstr_len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, str_ptr, str_len, nullptr, 0);
  std::basic_string<WideCharT> wstr(wstr_len, WideCharT{});
  MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, str_ptr, str_len, reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>(wstr.data()), wstr_len);
  return wstr;
}

template<typename WideCharT>
std::string convert_UTF16_to_UTF8(const std::basic_string<WideCharT>& wstr) {
  const wchar_t *wstr_ptr = reinterpret_cast<const wchar_t*>(wstr.c_str());
  int wstr_len = static_cast<int>(wstr.size());
  int str_len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wstr_ptr, wstr_len, nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr);
  std::string str(str_len, '\0');
  WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wstr_ptr, wstr_len, str.data(), str_len, nullptr, nullptr);
  return str;
}
```

```
std::wstring convert_to_wstring(const std::string& str) {
  return convert_UTF8_to_UTF16<wchar_t>(str);
}

std::u16string convert_to_u16string(const std::string& str) {
  return convert_UTF8_to_UTF16<char16_t>(str);
}

std::string convert_from_wstring(const std::wstring& wstr) {
  return convert_UTF16_to_UTF8(wstr);
}

std::string convert_from_u16string(const std::u16string& ustr) {
  return convert_UTF16_to_UTF8(ustr);
}
```

On Windows, `char16_t` and `wchar_t` are the same byte size, and both are used for UTF-16 strings, hence why you can safely use the APIs with `u16string` as well as `wstring`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked with minor changes (`utf_len` should be `wstr_len` and I changed `nil` to `nullptr`) and now I finally have something more reliable to work with `string`s!

Comment: @Markstar thanks, I fixed my example (been spending too much time in other languages lately)

Comment: Oh no, I have run into the next issue. It compiles and runs correctly when compiling the code using `node-gyp` (which is using `VS2022 (17.9.34701.34)`). However, compiling it with Visual Studio itself, the string conversions do not work.

Comment: @Markstar "*the string conversions do not work*" is not very descriptive. What exactly does not work? Do you get a compiler error? A runtime error? Bad data? Please be more specific.

Comment: Thank you for replying again, it really means a lot to me and I hope I can pay it forward sometime. I'm still trying to figure out what exactly the error is. I solved the first issue (in Visual Studio, I had to separate the function declarations from the definitions). However, I still have problems left and I think it is because in Visual Studio, the file is not stored in the correct encoding (so defining: `std::string filename = "föö.txt"` does not work).

Comment: @Markstar See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/utf-8-set-source-and-executable-character-sets-to-utf-8?view=msvc-170 You can also try using `std::string filename = "f\xC3\xB6\xC3\xB6.txt";` instead, or even `std::string filename = convert_from_wstring(L"föö.txt");` or `std::string filename = convert_from_u16string(u"föö.txt");`

Comment: Perfect! I'm hesitant to change the encoding for the whole project, but the other solutions work beautifully!